# Process to Process communication via COM in c#, including Callbacks

Tags: c#, process, interface, callback, com

Folks

OK - I was cleared to provide simple examples (just love lawyers)...

I need to provide an interface that a 3rd party application can use to communicate with my application (bi-directional) and the 3rd party group mandates that the interface is to be a COM interface - they provide a rudimentary specification for said interface.

Here is one of the easier interfaces for this communication:

```
[Guid("B751EA69-5E72-4DF0-8D3B-9DFA7A7ACCEF"),
 ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ARPOSCom : IARPOSCom
{
    public ARPOSCom() {}

    public string SendMsg(ref string Msg)
    { return "SendMsg Interface was triggered with Msg: [" + Msg + "]"; }
}
```

The Interface file looks like:

```
[Guid("5DBFD8FD-2D00-4107-BDAE-F046CDC4F19A"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IARPOSCom
{
    string SendMsg(ref string Msg);
}
```

Now presumably, they would do something like this to latch onto the interface:

```
// Instantiate the interface
ARPOSInterfaces.IARPOSCom IsbARPOSCom = (ARPOSInterfaces.IARPOSCom)new ARPOSInterfaces.ARPOSCom();
```

And then they may do something this like:

```
private void btnDoSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tboxMsgRec.Text = string.Empty;
    string inMsg = tboxMsgSend.Text;
    string rtrnVal = IsbARPOSCom.SendMsg(ref inMsg);
    tboxMsgRec.Text = rtrnVal;

    LogMsg("IsbARPOSCom.SendMsg triggered with return value = {" + tboxMsgRec.Text + "}");
}
```

This appears to work fine; however, the other half of the equation is for the SendMsg to be caught by the client and the appropriate action to be taken in my code.

All I seem to be able to do is make changes in the actual interface routines and I am not allowed to do that - I need to pass the inbound data to another application for that application to process and return the appropriate response which is in turned returned to the server/source.

I hope the samples help - I am going down with the ship and the kicker is - I am sure it is something straight-forward that I am not asking the correct question for.

Kind Regards,
Robert S.

Comment: Are we talking integration/communication over RESTful HTTP calls, or what?

Comment: The communication is via COM - not my choice, but I am bound to that due to the makers of the other software and they will not change it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003309/handling-com-callbacks-in-c-sharp-client?rq=1

Comment: Thanks - I will evaluate that and implement it in and see if that takes me closer - your time is greatly appreciated and I will post my findings (probably next week).

Comment: I should confess I'm not actually familiar with COM, I just noticed that similar question. You may want to make your question more specific - or search for other COM questions

Comment: Well, that did not solve the problem - I am nearly 100% sure I need to better explain and provide an example in code; hence, I am writing that out right now and will clean up the question accordingly.  I do appreciate all who have looked at these posts even i you were not able to provide help - I am stumped on this and I am sure it is a matter of asking the correct question to get my project back on track.